# vue.js and vue router. Why does the call of `new VueRouter() ` already modify the current URL?

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

I have a non SPA (multi page application). On one page I use a vue.js component with multiple tabs. I control those tabs with VueRouter. it all works well very well actually.

I am using vue 2 and vue-router 3.

I define the Router directly in the single file component like this.

```
<script>
// import Vue from 'vue';
import VueRouter from 'vue-router';

export default {
  name: 'ProductDisplay',
  router: new VueRouter({
    routes: [
      { name: 'offer', path: '/' },
      { name: 'posts', path: '/posts' },
      { name: 'reviews', path: '/reviews' }
    ],
  }),
}
</script>
```

This tabbed component is imported globally because the entire multipage application is driven by a single app.js file compiled by webpack.
My problem is now, that even on pages, where this component is not used at all (only `import ProductDisplay from product-display.vue` is present), this `new VueRouter({})` call affects the current URL by appending /#/ at the end.

e.g. loading my homepage https://www.example.com it ends up beeing https://www.example.com/#/

Just to clarify: this `ProductDisplay` component is NOT used on the homepage at all.
On the other hand, on the page where `ProductDisplay` is being used I expect the urls to be like this and it works well.

```
https://www.example.com/product#/
https://www.example.com/product#/posts
https://www.example.com/product#/reviews
```

Here is the entire JavaScript code (webpack + babel) loaded on the homepage if someone likes to analyze. https://pastebin.com/VAAvpfXA

Is there a way to avoid this behaviour, e.g. by explicitely activating/initiating a VueRouter object?